# How to debug specific code of Linux kernel?

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel

While there were times that you want to know how kernel's specific code work, the best way is to write your test code by including specific header files, e.g., I want to know how kernel's *kfifo* working , the first I need is including `<linux/kfifo.h>`.

But this is not work for me, by only include `<linux/kfifo.h>`, we must tell GCC the header file search path, some predefined macro like `__KERNEL__` and so on, is there any sample project did this before? or you can tell me how to debug these code without copy these code out and delete some useless feature.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach to debugging kernel infrastructure code (basically, everything not including device drivers) is to compile a kernel for uml architecture (`make config ARCH=um` and the usual stuff after; make sure to retain the debug symbols in the build). Then you can use your favorite user space debugger to run and analyze the obtained uml kernel (as it is a normal linux executable).

http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.12.1/Documentation/virtual/uml/UserModeLinux-HOWTO.txt

By the way, the linked howto is badly out of date - you don't need to download and patch anything; UML is part of the kernel for many years now. But it will get you started, especially if you google around a bit for additional details.